# What is the equivalent of attach/detach of TinyMCE in Ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am currently migrating all TinyMCE plugins to CKeditor and having trouble with InsertInline plugin.

In TinyMCE I have a code like this:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.wysiwyg.plugins['insertinline'] = {

  /**
   * Return whether the passed node belongs to this plugin.
   */
  isNode: function(node) {
    return ($(node).is('img.wysiwyg-inline-image'));
  },


  /**
   * Execute the button.
   */
  invoke: function(data, settings, instanceId) {
    alert(Drupal.t('This is a pseudo plugin/button.\nIt does not insert an inline image.\n\nPlease use the INSERT button from the image upload fieldset.'));
  },


  /**
   * Replace all <!-- INLINE:xxx;w=x;h=x --> tags with images.
   */
  attach: function(content, settings, instanceId) {
    that = this;

    // Replace inline images with physical image
    content = content.replace(new RegExp('<!-- INLINE:([0-9]*);w=([0-9]*);h=([0-9]*) -->', 'gi'), function($0, $1, $2, $3) { return that._getPlaceholder($1, $2, $3); });

    return content;
  },


  /**
   * Replace images with <!-- INLINE:xxx;w=x;h=x --> tags in content upon detaching editor.
   */
  detach: function(content, settings, instanceId) {
    var $content = $('<div>' + content + '</div>'); // No .outerHTML() in jQuery :(

    $.each($('img.wysiwyg-inline-image', $content), function (i, elem) {
      altText = ' ' + Drupal.checkPlain(elem.getAttribute('alt')) + ' ';

      if (elem.parentNode && elem.parentNode.parentNode && elem.parentNode.tagName == 'H2') {
        // Moving the current element to left side of H2 tag 
        elem.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createComment(altText), elem.parentNode);
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
      }
      else {
        elem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createComment(altText), elem);
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
      }
    });
    return $content.html();
  },


  /**
   * Helper function to return a HTML placeholder.
   */
  _getPlaceholder: function (fid, w, h) {
    if (!fid) {
      fid = '';
    }
    if (!w) {
      w = '240';
    }
    if (!h) {
      h = '240';
    }

    // Grab image detail data
    var imgData = Drupal.cnngo_inline.getInlineImageDetail(fid, w, h);

    // Build and return image tag
    return '<img src="' + imgData.src + '" alt="' + imgData.alt + '" title="' + imgData.title + '" class="wysiwyg-inline-image" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '" />';
  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

**How it works:**

Let say I uploaded a 600x600 px image and I inserted it in the WYSIWYG area by default it will insert an img tag

[image]

When I click the "Insert" button as described in the image. It will insert img tag like this

```
<img class="wysiwyg-inline-image" title="Inline image 240x240" src="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/styles/inline_image_temp_240x240/public/2013/05/28/600x600_1.png" alt="INLINE:142879;w=240;h=240" width="240" height="240" data-mce-src="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/styles/inline_image_temp_240x240/public/2013/05/28/600x600_1.png">
```

See the image below.

[image]

Now if I'm going to detached the editor (clicked the Switch to plain text) the img tag is replaced by

```
<p><!-- INLINE:142879;w=240;h=240 --></p>
```

[image]

And it will show the img tag (will render the img) when I turned the editor back on.

Can someone point me in the right direction of what is the equivalent of detact/attach in Ckeditor.

I spent hours in Google but can't find the exact answer (maybe my question is not right).

Comment: It'd be easier if you describe what those methods do in TinyMCE.

Comment: @Reinmar...In tinymce when I detached the editor (switched to source) the img tag will be replaced by this "<!-- INLINE:142879;w=240;h=240 -->" then when I turned on the editor again it will show the image.

Comment: Hm... You haven't found anything because CKEditor does not equivalent of this feature. You could pretty easily implement this using dataProcessor, but... why? What do you want to achieve using this?

Comment: You uploaded too much screenshots. Please, keep your question as short as possible. Otherwise, no one will read it.

Comment: Oh sorry about that...for some reason we are saving the img tag in the DB using this "<!-- INLINE:142879;w=240;h=240 -->" and we have a filter that replace "<!-- INLINE:142879;w=240;h=240 -->" with the real image tag when the content is being rendered in the browser.

Comment: Hmm... in this case check [CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor) and [CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter usages in its code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/htmldataprocessor.js#L489-L620).